# Running dash on JupyterLab returns an error

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I tried to follow an example of building a data dashboard from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-your-own-data-dashboard-93e4848a0dcf).
This is the code run on JupyterLab.

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
```

But, activating the Dash server using the following code return error.

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Error message:

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3334: UserWarning:

To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
```

I changed `debug=True` with `debug=False`, but the server (`http://127.0.0.1:8050/`) is not opening. Instead, it keeps processing without opening a new page.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [jupyter-plotly-dash](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-plotly-dash/) but it is in "alpha" development phase. It is recommended to install it and run in `virtualenv`. It is known it gives issues when using system-python.

You will probably also need to run:

```
sudo pip3 install jupyter_server_proxy
jupyter serverextension enable jupyter_server_proxy
```

See also [this discussion](https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/jupyter-plotly-dash/issues/6) on github.

Comment: thanks. I applied that, but the same error message arises.

Comment: Did you use `virtualenv` to install `jupyter-plotly-dash` and run `jupyter notebook` ?